# How to add a new component when Angular app fails to bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrapping, initializer, angular-errorhandler

I have a question about my Angular app, I have an app that gets its initial config data from an API and can bootstrap the app using those config. Here is the ApiConfigService:

```
export class ApiConfigService {
    public initialized: Promise<any>;

    constructor(
        private readonly windowService: WindowService
    ) {
        this.initialized = window.configReady;
    }
}
```

Here is the Api config factory:

```
import { ApiConfigService } from '../services/api-config.service';

export function fetchApiConfigFactory(
    apiConfigService: ApiConfigService
) {
    return () => apiConfigService.initialized;
}
```

and in my app module this is what I have in my provider:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: fetchApiConfigFactory, multi: true, deps: [ApiConfigService] },
```

So app initialization is dependent of the promise coming from window.ConfigReady. If window.ConfigReady resolves and has the proper data app will be initialized and everything is good.

Now I am about to add a new functionality that there are cases where the config is not present and I need to implement a sign in page and show it to user and then after sign in the config will be fetched and app will be initialized. I am wondering how can I implement the sign in compomenent to this structure? Basically I need add somehow to the app module that when window.ConfigReady is not present use another component `signInComponent` to show it to user. Any help and guild on how to this in Angular will be really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have injected the service using APP_INITIALIZER in to the App module which means , it will execute before the application regardless of any component on your application . In your case I would suggest to go with routing approach , for each routing url you can create a Route resolver which will execute before load the component specified to the route.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '/home', component: HomeComponent,resolve:{config:ConfigResolver} },
    { path: '/SignIn', component: SignInComponent },

    {path:'404',component:Error404Component}

];
```

Also in your appConfigService check whether the data is already loaded, because the service will execute when each route activate , So inside service you no need to pull the data again from any API.

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is without data coming from window.configReady , this apiConfigService is not working. I need to bootstrap the app in another way that handles where the window.configReady is not there.